# Using weights in CrossEntropyLoss and BCELoss (PyTorch)

Tags: pytorch, loss-function

I am training a PyTorch model to perform binary classification. My minority class makes up about 10% of the data, so I want to use a weighted loss function. The docs for `BCELoss` and `CrossEntropyLoss` say that I can use a `'weight'` for each sample.

However, when I declare `CE_loss = nn.BCELoss()` or `nn.CrossEntropyLoss()` and then do `CE_Loss(output, target, weight=batch_weights)`, where `output`, `target`, and `batch_weights` are `Tensor`s of `batch_size`, I get the following error message:

```py
forward() got an unexpected keyword argument 'weight'
```

Answer (score 11):

Another way you could accomplish your goal is to use `reduction=none` when initializing the loss and then multiply the resulting tensor by your weights before computing the mean.
e.g.

```
loss = torch.nn.BCELoss(reduction='none')
model = torch.sigmoid

weights = torch.rand(10,1)
inputs = torch.rand(10,1)
targets = torch.rand(10,1)

intermediate_losses = loss(model(inputs), targets)
final_loss = torch.mean(weights*intermediate_losses)
```

Of course for your scenario you still would need to calculate the weights tensor. But hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 5):

Could it be that you want to apply separate fixed weights to all elements of class 0 and class 1 in your dataset? It is not clear what value you are passing for batch_weights here. If so, then that is not what the weight parameter in BCELoss does. The weight parameter expects you to pass a separate weight for every ELEMENT in the dataset, not for every CLASS. There are several ways around this. You could construct a weight table for every element. Alternatively, you could use a custom loss function that does what you want:

```
def BCELoss_class_weighted(weights):

    def loss(input, target):
        input = torch.clamp(input,min=1e-7,max=1-1e-7)
        bce = - weights[1] * target * torch.log(input) - (1 - target) * weights[0] * torch.log(1 - input)
        return torch.mean(bce)

  return loss
```

Note that it is important to add a clamp to avoid numerical instability.

HTH Jeroen

Answer (score 1):

the issue is wherein your providing the *weight* parameter. As it is mentioned in the docs, [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCELoss.html#torch.nn.BCELoss), the weights parameter should be provided during module instantiation.

For example, something like,

```py
from torch import nn
weights = torch.FloatTensor([2.0, 1.2]) 
loss = nn.BCELoss(weights=weights)
```

You can find a more concrete example [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/5157#issuecomment-373304843) or another helpful PT forum discussion [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/dealing-with-imbalanced-datasets-in-pytorch/22596/4).

Comment: The documentation for BCELoss says that 'weight' should be 'a manual rescaling weight given to the loss of each batch element. If given, has to be a Tensor of size nbatch.' What if the weights will change for each batch?

Comment: On the face of it I don't think that's possible. On top of it, I think having per-batch dynamic rescaling weights might have a negative impact on learning,as the loss function attributes are constantly changing per batch.

Comment: BCELoss does not work like this.  The weights are for the batch elements.  Try it: `bce_loss = torch.nn.BCELoss(weight=torch.tensor([1, 50]))` then `labels = torch.tensor(np.random.randn(12) > 1).double()` then `outputs = torch.nn.Sigmoid(torch.tensor(np.random.randn(12))).double()` then `bce_loss(outputs, labels)` results in the following error.

"RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (12) must match the size of tensor b (2) at non-singleton dimension 0"

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass weights like below:

```
CE_loss = CrossEntropyLoss(weight=[…])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to the idea of @Jeroen Vuurens, but the class weights are determined by the target mean:

```py
y_train_mean = y_train.mean()
            
bi_cls_w2 = 1/(1 - y_train_mean)
bi_cls_w1 = 1/y_train_mean - bi_cls_w2

bce_loss = nn.BCELoss(reduction='none')
loss_fun = lambda pred, target: ((bi_cls_w1*target + bi_cls_w2) * bce_loss(pred, target)).mean()
```